# How to publish a web site via (linux) script

Tags: html, ftp, publish

I'm just finished with a nice HTML5+ JQM web site on my Ubuntu laptop.
A make script converts server side code to static HTML, optimizes images and compresses JTML, JavaScript and CSS.

I ask what's the method you'd suggest to upload it to my public server (I have an ftp access, no ssh).
It should be a strong, repeatable and flexible (remove deleted files on server, upload only changed files, for example?) solution, which should be automated.

Comment: You want a commandline ftp-client?

Comment: Perhaps. If it can accomplish the requested tasks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic solution  which you need to modify for your needs

- ls your changed files and save in an array(? or may be a list)
- connect to FTP
- upload changed content
- disconnect

Best would be to set up a versioning system that will cover the files deleted, modified etc. Set up GIT and use GIT commands to get a list of changed files and use command line FTP to upload files.

Comment: Nice. Could I use GIT to update directly to FTP server?

Comment: Not sure about GIT. I have some automated servers which deploy automatically when I push code to my GIT repo. May be you can set up GIT to fire a script for you for every push.